# Unexpected Verilog bit manipulation

Tags: fpga, verilog

I am a C programmer with lots of experience with bit manipulation and 2s compliment. I find Verilog doesn't act quite like I expect, which causes me to do more trial and error than I would like.

I understand that signed arithmetic in Verilog, requires that everything should be signed. I wonder it there is some other rule that I am missing.

Question 1:

```
reg signed [12:0] position;  
position = position - 1'b1;  //this worked

position = position - 1'sb1  //this seemed to subtract a negative 1, the opposite of my intention.
```

Did the synthesizer fill my 1 out to 13 bits carrying out the sign bit?  Should I have used 13'sb1 instead.  When can I get away with the conceptually simpler 1'b1, or even just 1?

Question 2:

```
reg signed [12:0] position, PWMgo;

reg doForward, doReverse;

if(position  > PWMgo - 1'sd1) begin   //this works

if(position  > PWMgo - !(doForward || doReverse))  begin // this doesn't work

if(position  > PWMgo - ~(doForward | doReverse))  begin // this doesn't work either
```

Explanation: In the C world doForward and doReverse are both bits and can either be used as bits or as the numbers 0 or 1. My intention here is to do some bit manipulation on these two bits and subtract the result (a 1 or 0) from PWMgo. I am doing this to avoid several confusing lines of if statements.

I have been asked what I mean by "this doesn't work".  What I mean is that I was expecting PWMgo to be either decremented, or unchanged, an expectation that was unfulfilled.

Comment: Post a complete Verilog code sample that we can simulate ourselves (a full module).  Use `$display` to show what your simulation outputs, and what you expect it to output.  You really should have update your previously closed question instead of asking this duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

`1'sb1` is a single bit `1`. Marking it as a signed value is making it a 2's complement representation. But `1` when interpreted as a single-bit 2's complement is actually `-1`. So you expression

```
position = position - 1'sb1;
```

is subtracting *negative* `1`, that is adding positive `1`.

(Here is a [demonstration](https://edaplayground.com/x/tBT2))

Same for the second question. Your comment "this works" cannot be true, unless your expectations are opposite to the intention. Consequently the "this doesn't work" ones are probably working.

Comment: The downvoter, please explain.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation of 1'sb1.  That was exactly the information I needed.

Here is another related mystery:

   `(signedFourBitReg  > 4'sd3 - !unsignedOneBitRegSetToZero)  
    (signedFourBitReg  > 4'sd3 - ~unsignedOneBitRegSetToZero)`

Explain to me why these two fragments evaluate differently.

!unsignedOneBitRegSetToZero evaluates to 1 (my intention) whereas
~unsignedOneBitRegSetToZero evaluates to -1

Is there a rule to help keep me from falling into this trap?

Doug

Comment: That's an interesting quirk, maybe you should ask another question about it. I don't have a definitive answer for you even though tried to do some research and experimentation...  The `!unsignedOneBitRegSetToZero` and `~unsignedOneBitRegSetToZero` expressions by themselves yield a result of the same type and value, so it is not clear to me how the context (subtraction) can affect it. *maybe* StackOverflow would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I asked it for you (and my own curiosity) right here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75769923/result-of-single-bit-bitwise-vs-logical-inversion-is-interpreted-differently-in

Comment: !0 and ~0 does the same thing.  Doug

Comment: @Tinkerer They do while stand-alone, but when in an expression - they behave differently. Take a look at my question on StackOverflow, it has now all of the required information. The Verilog expression rules are quite different from the other languages.

Comment: Eugene,  Thanks for posting that on stackexchange.  It sort of makes sense to me.  I suppose I may fall into the same hole 6 months from now.  Doug